# Non-asymptotic results for M-estimators?

Tags: st.statistics

Does anyone know if there are any standard non-asymptotic results for M-estimators? I'm looking for finite-sample guarantees. Figured maybe someone here might know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform Berry--Esseen-type bounds on the rate of convergence to normality for $M$-estimators were obtained by Michel and Phanzagl -- see e.g. Refs. [14, 16, 17] in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ejs/1491897618). In the latter paper, a non-uniform Berry--Esseen-type bound for maximum likelihood estimators was given as well, with sufficiently detailed instructions (on page 1176) on how to the extend this result to $M$-estimators.

Comment: That is a very nice and interesting paper. However, are such bounds on convergence rates enough to call these "finite-sample guarantee"? What I mean is, convergence rates are still given in big-O, and so might hide very large constants. This is in contrast to cases where you can construct "exact" p-values (Fisher's exact test or the Wilcoxon rank sum test under a location-shift assumption). I guess I'm asking what the distinction is between "finite sample guarantees" and "exact" tests?

Comment: @RHahn : The mentioned results are apparently the state of the art. Yet indeed, the constants in the bounds, if made explicit, will likely be way too large to be useful for small samples. The problem is that it is very hard to obtain even the existing bounds. To put this into the right perspective, let us recall that the best constant in the uniform Berry--Esseen (BE) bound is still unknown even in the simplest case of sums of iid r.v.'s.

Comment: Previous comment continued: The best known constant in the nonuniform BE bound, even in this simplest case, is apparently very far from the best possible constant -- see e.g. shorturl.at/jmnwI, https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2828, https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0516. One can also see (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1460463653) how much effort went into getting somewhat moderate (and yet likely far from optimal) constants in the uniform BE-type bound for the Pearson correlation coefficient -- which appears much easier to deal with than the $M$-estimators.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information!

Comment: @IosifPinelis do the results in your paper also hold for vector-valued instead of scalar parameters?

Comment: @Glassjawed : No, those results don't hold for vector-valued parameters. Substantial modifications of the method have to be made to achieve that.

Comment: Which parts of the method would I have to modify? I figured out how to modify it for M-estimators (result is that I have a ratio of two expectations instead of the Fisher information in my bound).

Comment: @Glassjawed : I think modifications, quite possibly nontrivial, will be needed throughout.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I see. Yeah when I modified it for a specific M-estimator, I also don't think the results hold for exponential families and some of the distributions listed since the new estimator I have wasn't necessarily concave (although the log-likelihood is). Trying to figure out how to show the convergence holds for some common model families though. Should I just message you privately?

Comment: @Glassjawed : Right now I am occupied by working on other problems, but I think the case of a vector-valued parameter is something worth thinking about, and maybe I will consider it in the future.